# Flutter Firebase clustering_google_maps

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

The goal is to produce google map markers using clusters from information in memory. Currently, I'm downloading LATLNG points from Firebase into local memory. Next the goal is to display these collection of point on a map in a Flutter app using the Google Maps clustering feature. To achieve this, there is a dependency called `clustering_google_maps 0.0.4+2` which allows for access to data from a local database (SQLite) or from local memory.

The developer recommends with large marker sets in the thousands it's best to use a local database (SQLite). In my case, I only have 20 - 40 total markers. Can someone help provide a solution to explain how one can use the data from local memory to display on the Google Map?

[Quick Example from the Repo](https://github.com/giandifra/clustering_google_maps#quick-example-for-both-solution)

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<LatLngAndGeohash> list;

  HomeScreen({Key key, this.list}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ClusteringHelper clusteringHelper;
  final CameraPosition initialCameraPosition =
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.000000, 0.000000), zoom: 0.0);

  Set<Marker> markers = Set();

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController mapController) async {
    print("onMapCreated");
    if (widget.list == null) {
      clusteringHelper.database = await AppDatabase.get().getDb();
    }
    clusteringHelper.updateMap();
  }

  updateMarkers(Set<Marker> markers) {
    setState(() {
      this.markers = markers;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.list != null) {
      initMemoryClustering();
    } else {
      initDatabaseClustering();
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  // For db solution
  initDatabaseClustering() {
    clusteringHelper = ClusteringHelper.forDB(
      dbGeohashColumn: FakePoint.dbGeohash,
      dbLatColumn: FakePoint.dbLat,
      dbLongColumn: FakePoint.dbLong,
      dbTable: FakePoint.tblFakePoints,
      updateMarkers: updateMarkers,
    );
  }

  // For memory solution
  initMemoryClustering() {
    clusteringHelper = ClusteringHelper.forMemory(
      list: widget.list,
      updateMarkers: updateMarkers,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Clustering Example"),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
        markers: markers,
        onCameraMove: (newPosition) => clusteringHelper.onCameraMove(newPosition, forceUpdate: false),
        onCameraIdle: clusteringHelper.onMapIdle,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child:
            widget.list == null ? Icon(Icons.content_cut) : Icon(Icons.update),
        onPressed: () {
          if (widget.list == null) {
            clusteringHelper.whereClause = "WHERE ${FakePoint.dbLat} > 42.6";
            clusteringHelper.updateMap();
          } else {
            clusteringHelper.updateMap();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will introduce this function in next release stay tuned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](https://github.com/giandifra/clustering_google_maps#memory-technique)

> MEMORY TECHNIQUE
>   To work properly you must have a list of LatLngAndGeohash object. LatLngAndGeohash is a simple object with Location and Geohash property, the last is generated automatically; you need only location of the point.
>
> For this solution you must use the MEMORY constructor of
>   ClusteringHelper:

```
ClusteringHelper.forMemory(...);
```

To test this feature you can clone the [giandifra/clustering_google_maps](https://github.com/giandifra/clustering_google_maps) repo. Then modify the splash.dart file using the following code. when calling the HomeScreen from splash.dart

```
  List<LatLngAndGeohash> markerList = new List<LatLngAndGeohash>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    markerList.add(LatLngAndGeohash(LatLng(34.0522, -118.2437)));
    markerList.add(LatLngAndGeohash(LatLng(34.0522, -118.2647)));
    markerList.add(LatLngAndGeohash(LatLng(34.0522, -118.2467)));
    markerList.add(LatLngAndGeohash(LatLng(34.0522, -118.2487)));
    markerList.add(LatLngAndGeohash(LatLng(34.0522, -118.2707)));
  }

 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        ....
        HomeScreen(list: markerList)
```